# How do you show content on certain day

Tags: twig

Im trying to show a different page on certain days.
But I can't really figure it out in twig.

```
{% if "now" | date("l") %}
    {% if "Sunday" %}
    Sunday content
    {% elseif "Tuesday" %}
    Tuesday content
    {% elseif "Wednesday" %}
    Wednesday
    {% else %}
    default
   {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
```

This ofcourse isnt working.
Is there any way to do this with Twig?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the issue.
The code should be:

```
{% if "now" | date('l') == 'Wednesday' %}
```